# Test gas cooktop without a gas line?

Tags: appliances, natural-gas, propane

I've found a great deal on a used cooktop. We're eventually going to remodel the kitchen so have been collecting things as we go along.

The catch is that this cooktop is for natural gas, and we have propane. I'll eventually be getting the propane conversion kit, but in the interim, is there any way I can test this (in case it needs to be returned) without having access to natural gas lines? Is there any form of canister fuel that I could hook up to it to test that would act like natural gas?